# How do I stop Phonegap iPad loading screen shrinking?

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova

I have phonegap's latest build 0.9.5.1. This app I am creating is only for the iPad. The only problem I am getting is the loading screen is fine at the start, then just before the webview loads, it shrinks it to the top left corner to the size of the iphone.

Steps I have tried so far has failed. I tried navigator.notification.loading(options) method. Also tried to edit the phonegapdelegate.m but no avail.

If I'm honest, I don't think xcode 4 is building any changes I make to the phoengap framework. Possibly this is the key to it all?

So, what I am asking is, how do i stop this shrinking loading screen? or how I get what I have changed in the phonegap framework to build in xcode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the splash screen, all you need to do is delete the default.png and replace it with a splash screen of your choice that is the size of the iPad's screen (1024x768). It should also be named "default.png"

Comment: Excuse me, 1004x768. The height of the status bar must be subtracted